# Jest tests passing individually but failing when run together

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, jestjs

I have a few Jest tests that are passing when run individually but are failing when run together. As far as I can tell the tests are self contained but they must be interacting in some way that I'm missing.

The tests are testing a connection adaptor that tries to connect to a BLE device multiple times while only returning a single pending connection that can be awaited or cancelled.

Here are the tests:

```
test("connect returns pending connection", async () => {
  const adaptor = new MockAdaptor();

  const pendingConnection = adaptor.connect("test");
  expect(pendingConnection.id).toBe("test");

  await pendingConnection.cancel();
})

test('connect success', async () => {
  const adaptor = new MockAdaptor();

  const pendingConnection = adaptor.connect("test");

  // TEST FAILING HERE
  const connection = await pendingConnection.connectionPromise as any;

  expect(connection).toBe("test");
})
```

Here is the code shared by the tests:

```
const getSuccessfulPendingConnection = () => ({
  address: "test",
  connectionPromise: new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("test"), 1000)
  }),
  cancel: async () => {}
})

const getFailedPendingConnection = () => ({
  address: "test",
  connectionPromise: new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject("connect failed"), 1000);
  }),
  cancel: async () => {}
})

const getMockPendingConnection = (id: string) => {
  if(id === "test") {
    return getSuccessfulPendingConnection();
  }

  return getFailedPendingConnection();
}

class MockAdaptor {
  connect(id: string) {
    let rejectPromise = () => {};
    let cancelConnection = async () => {};
    let connectionCancelled = false;
    const connectionPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      rejectPromise = () => {
        reject("Connection cancelled")
        connectionCancelled = true;
      };
      
      let newConnection = undefined;
      while(!connectionCancelled) {
        try {
          const pendingConnection = getMockPendingConnection(id);
          cancelConnection = pendingConnection.cancel;
          newConnection = await pendingConnection.connectionPromise;
          return resolve(newConnection);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Connection failed', error);
        }
      }
    });

    const cancel = async () => {
      rejectPromise();
      await cancelConnection();
    }

    return {
      id,
      connectionPromise,
      cancel,
    }
  }
}
```

When I run these tests together, 'connect returns pending connection' passes, but 'connect success' fails with the message "Connection cancelled".

Comment: could the connection still be in use when running a new test - thus failing due to it not being able to connect?

Comment: @altruios the tests don't create actual connections. They create fake pending connections with a connection promise that just resolves to an address (string) after 1 second. Also the test fails with a "Connection cancelled" message indicating that cancelling the promise in the first test is cancelling the promise in the second test somehow.